# Phonegap - gap in tutorial for iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova

Despite the title, I fully expect this to be a user error.

I've done mostly native Android development, and now I'm trying to get an HTML5/Phonegap application going on iOS. I'm following the extended "getting started" tutorial [Here](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/39991939/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-iOS-using-Xcode-4-%28Template-Version%29). I get the application up and running on a physical test device, but my phonegap functionality is non-responsive, so something is amiss.

Take a look at the following screenshots from the tutorial, we'll call this step 3:

[image]

The screenshot above is what my project looks like at this point. I see the PhoneGap.framework in there, so I'm feeling optimistic. Step 4 says, drag your "WWW" folder into your project, which I did (assuming the red box indicates the landing zone), and I was prompted with the screenshot presented in the tutorial, I selected the same options..

[image: Step 5]

Step 5 shows the screenshot above. Notice the differences:

1. PhoneGap.framework isn't there anymore
2. There is another project in the workspace called PhoneGapLib.xcodeproj

There was only one simple step in between, yet the project looks very different. It seems to me, that more things happened than just dragging the www folder?? I know thousands of people are using PhoneGap with iOS, so I'm hoping one of you can shine a light on what went wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like this was indeed a user error. When you create the PhoneGap project, you're supposed to run a build before you do anything. This generates the www folder, but doesn't actually add it to your project. You have to go to the folder location where your app resides, and drag the created www folder into the project.

I was dragging my own www folder that already had my code that works in Android. Not sure why this didn't work.

In my defense, even now that it's working, my project doesn't look like the screenshot above with the additional phonegap project. Either way - I hope this saves someone some time...

Comment: Where would you get the PhoneGap.framework now? I need it to make a legacy project run. Any ideas? It seems the the links above have changed since you posted them.